# mvn archetype:generate which version selected

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-archetype

According to [doc](https://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/generate-mojo.html) , there is no default value for `<archetypeVersion>`.

So, when I do `mvn archetype:generate` , and I select an archetype , then it might be possible that many versions of it might exist in repository. Which will be selected ?

Example :

In the repository - https://nexus.opendaylight.org/content/repositories/opendaylight.snapshot/archetype-catalog.xml , there are basically 2 archetypes with 2 versions each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your meta-data you should be able to specify a release version, here is the example from quickstart:

```
cat /cygdrive/c/Users/G01103266/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/archetypes/maven-archetype-quickstart/maven-metadata-central.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<metadata>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.archetypes</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-archetype-quickstart</artifactId>
  <versioning>
    <latest>1.4</latest>
    <release>1.4</release>
    <versions>
      <version>1.0-alpha-1</version>
      <version>1.0-alpha-2</version>
      <version>1.0-alpha-3</version>
      <version>1.0-alpha-4</version>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <version>1.1</version>
      <version>1.3</version>
      <version>1.4</version>
    </versions>
    <lastUpdated>20181213005348</lastUpdated>
  </versioning>
</metadata>
```

In your local repository or Nexus/Artifactory you may have an [archetype-catalog.xml](https://maven.apache.org/archetype/archetype-models/archetype-catalog/archetype-catalog.html) this will define the allowed versions, for you to choose from, [here](http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml) is the one for Maven Central.

If there is no mention of the archetype in the catalog the version will default to 1.0.

If there is more than one version it will ask you to pick a version and default to release.

I create test projects with the following script

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.maven.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DarchetypeVersion=RELEASE
```

Will use version 1.4

Comment: So, you are saying that whatever archetype I select (not necessarily quick start) , I need to see the `<release>` (in its corresponding maven-metadata-central.xml ) which version is mentioned there ? But before that maven needs to decide which artifact of archetype it has to download ? Does not it needs to version before downloading ? Or it downloads all ?

Comment: But you are passing the version argument.  I just run `mvn archetype:generate`. So what will happen now ?

Comment: I also checked. Your first part of update is correct. However , if the artifact is not present in catalogue , then I am seeing , it is searching the archetype with version 1.0. Can you please verify once ? In our artifactory version 1.0 does not exist and it is failing. (Though this is not a problem. We know what version to keep)

Comment: @BreakingBenjamin yes, I tested that with maven-archetype-webapp which is not in my local catalog,will update answer for anyone else looking.

Comment: Thnx for the update. I have one doubt. You mentioned `it asks you to pick a version, the default will be release` , when will this happen ? What did you meant by `archetype is not mentioned`. mentioned where ? If not mentioned in catalogue , then it will 1.0 as you mentioned. So, when will default be release ? If possible, please simply the scenarios point wise, so that it is easier to grasp for us.

Comment: @BreakingBenjamin updated again, good answer I think, but you've done a lot of the work :)